# Throttle method call RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, accessibilityservice

I would like to use `RxJava` to throttle the amount of `AccessibilityEvent`'s I'm getting from the `android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService` in particular the [TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED).

It gets fired every time the user typs anything in an `EditText` widget. However I tried using `debounce`, `throttleLast`, `throttleFirst` or even `buffer`. However I'm not sure how exactly I should use them if I don't already have all the events I want to emit.

```
public class AccessibilityService extends android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService {

    @Inject
    AccessibilityServiceController accessibilityServiceController;

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Timber.d("AccessibilityEvent was received: " + event.toString());
        //Throttle so I only get the last event in XXX milliseconds.
        accessibilityServiceController.evaluateEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Timber.e("Service was interrupted! ");
    }
}
```

I want something similar to `debounce` used on this `EditText` widget
[Kaushik Gopal's DebounceSearchEmitterFragment.java](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/fragments/DebounceSearchEmitterFragment.java)

So my output can be:

[this is]

[this is a ]

[this is a test]

instead of:

[t]

[th ]

[thi ]

[this ]

...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What means : 'However I'm not sure how exactly I should use them if I don't already have all the events I want to emit.' ?
Are you having problems creating an obsersable from your event ? 
Or just choosing the right filter operator ?

Comment: I basically want to add Objects to my onNext after I created my Observable. And then apply the correct filter to get my desired output. If I would have my List with events when I made the observable I could just use Observable.from() however i want to 'push' events to my observable.

Comment: So what's the problem using debounce ? Can you plz post your rx related code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

I found out there is something as a `PublishSubject`/`Subject`.

I can basically post to onNext as some sort of setter after the creation of an `Observable` which is what I was after.

```
public class AccessibilityService extends android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService {
    private final PublishSubject<AccessibilityEvent> accessibilityEventPublishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    public AccessibilityServiceControllerImpl() {
        accessibilityEventPublishSubject
                .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<AccessibilityEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
                        Log.d(TAG, accessibilityEvent.toString());
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluateEvent(final AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        int type = accessibilityEvent.getEventType();
        switch (type) {
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:
                Timber.d("Event received in controller: " + accessibilityEvent.toString());
                accessibilityEventPublishSubject.onNext(accessibilityEvent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This was the answer to this question. However I'm facing empty objects as they are recycled by `executeMessage` in `android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService`.

```
@Override
public void executeMessage(Message message) {
    switch (message.what) {
        case DO_ON_ACCESSIBILITY_EVENT: {
            AccessibilityEvent event = (AccessibilityEvent) message.obj;
            if (event != null) {
                AccessibilityInteractionClient.getInstance().onAccessibilityEvent(event);
                mCallback.onAccessibilityEvent(event);
                try {
                    //EVENT IS RECYCLED BEFORE THE ONNEXT IS CALLED IN MY PUBLISHSUBJECT
                    event.recycle();
                } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                }
            }
        } return;
... bla bla
```

But I guess that is worth another question here.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

- Create an observable which sets an "accessibility listener"
- This listener can start the RxJava stream of events
- Subscribe to the stream, and have the service controller evaluate the event at the appropriate time

A key thing to redesigning something so that it's reactive is making sure everything in your code becomes a *trigger* of some kind. A callback doesn't do much if if you need some logic from the stream.

Below is an example:

```
AccessibilityServiceController accessibilityServiceController;
Action1<AccessibilityEvent> accessibilityEventListener;

AccessibilityService() {
    accessibilityServiceController = new AccessibilityServiceController();
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<AccessibilityEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super AccessibilityEvent> subscriber) {
            accessibilityEventListener = new Action1<AccessibilityEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void call(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
                    subscriber.onNext(accessibilityEvent);
                }
            };
        }
    })
    .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // <-----
    .subscribe(new Action1<AccessibilityEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void call(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
            accessibilityServiceController.evaluateEvent(accessibilityEvent);
        }
    });

}

private void setAccessibilityEventListener(Action1<AccessibilityEvent> listener) {
    accessibilityEventListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    // This will be throttled every 500 Milliseconds
    accessibilityEventListener.call(event);
}
```

You might not want to put this stuff in the constructor but you get the idea. **Build the `Observable` into the listener**. I'd also recommend keeping a reference to the `Subscription`, as it's important to unsubscribe in order to prevent memory leaks!